# React Router hash router do not re-render the view

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, history

I have a front-end app built on top of react/redux/react-router. Now, I try to set up hash router. However, it only works on URL, but it does not re-render the UI.

Only way to see the view change is to refresh the browser. Then, now I see the view for the url.

When I used browser router, it automatically re-rendered the views. It will be great help if you can tell me what I missed for this current situation.

EDIT: Added my code

```
// index.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Home } from './containers/home';
import { SMS } from './containers/sms';

import { history, store } from './store';

export const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router basename="/" history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/call" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/sms" component={SMS} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
 </Provider>
);

// store.ts  
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory, createHashHistory } from 'history';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { storage } from '../services/local-storage';
import { callsReducer } from './calls/reducer';

import { Call } from '../interfaces/call.interface';
import { CallMap } from '../interfaces/call-map.interface';

const STORAGE_NAME = 'SIP_CALL_SIMULATOR';

const {
  loadState,
  saveState,
} = storage({
  name: STORAGE_NAME,
  localStorage,
});

interface RootState {
  calls: CallMap;
}

const initialState: RootState = {
  calls: {},
};

const persistedState = loadState(initialState);
const reducer = combineReducers({
  calls: callsReducer,
  routing: routerReducer,
});

const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

// const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
const hashHistory = createHashHistory();
// const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(`Updated the redux store.`);
  const state = store.getState();
  console.log(state);
  saveState(state);
});

export { history, store };
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Only way to see the view change is to refresh the browser." what are the URLs you are trying to reach are you sure your internal links are right?

Comment: Can you provide your code we can't guess

Comment: @Liam I added my code

Comment: @Maxwelll the url is http://localhost:8000/simulator.html#/call

Comment: @supergentle shouldnt your path should just be /call `basename="/"` AND `<Route exact path="/call" component={Home} />`

Comment: @Maxwelll i think that is the case when i use browser history, but here i am using hash router. And i dont see the problem with that.

Comment: @supergentle I'm having the same issue. Did you figure it out?